Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: premium gmail
We coded a script which saves attachments from emails automatically in the Google Drive. The script should get a trigger to do that every hour for the new mails.
The script works perfect, but after a few hours it stopped working with this error text:

Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: premium gmail.

So what can I do to get the script running again?
I coded the script yesterday and today it still has this problem.
I found that website which describes the quotas:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
But that doesn't help me so much because I don't know which limit is responsible for this problem. I chatted with the AI-support chat on this website, it says there are too many API-progresses...
The google workspace support is not able to help me with it...
I need to solve this problem fast. So which limit is responsible for my problem?
Is there any chance to increase the limit for that script?

Hi! Can you give more information on how your solution works, please highlight the frequency of the calls from the API this will give the community will have better oversight on what is happening.

Google Apps Script has two tiers, one for free accounts and another for Google Workspace accounts. Besides switching from one tier to another, there is no way to increase the Google Apps Script quotas.
One option might be to use the Gmail API instead of the Gmail Service or the Advanced Gmail Service. The quotas are described in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota.
For this

Create a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project
Enable the Gmail API
Set up the OAuth Authorization screen.
Update the Google Apps Script project with the GCP project ID
Update your project to use the Gmail API by using UrlFetchApp to make the API calls and log detailed error messages.

If you get an error again, look at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors.  I.E., if you get "Daily limit exceeded" you might request an additional quota. The details are included in the above link.
